# Copying & Pasting

Tags: excel, vba

Objective: I'm trying to copy, find and paste data as per the find (that is Region).

Problem: I'm getting the desired output when I'm defining where to paste the data. But this is not what the macro is suppose to do. It's suppose to look for that Region name and then paste the data under the appropriate title and so on.

Here is what I've written so far:

```
Sub DataPasting()

ApplicationUpdating = False

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I2:J2").Copy        'copy and pasting the data set from Sheet1
Sheets("Stories & Topics").Select

    Dim RegionColumn As Long
    Dim erow As String


    RegionColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Raw").Range("H1"), Sheets("Stories & Topics").Range("A1:Z1"), False)

    erow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stories & Topics").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stories & Topics").Paste (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stories & Topics").Range("B" & erow + 1))

        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


ApplicationUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Note:

Sheet1 = Sheet from where the data is to be copied
Stories & Topics = Destination sheet where the data has to be pasted

I also tried Vlookup and Match but no use.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Selection.PasteSpecial will always paste result to the current selection, but I don't see any .select  before

Comment: Paste Special is to paste a Numeric Value in the destination sheet because the value is obtained through a formula and there will be a Referencing error. And even if I move the Paste Special the output is still not being pasted under the correct header and it's because we have defined that it need to be pasted in "B" (if you check "erow" & pasting code below) we want the location to be based on the Correct Region which has been selected and it should be random.

Comment: I'm attaching a screenshot of the main sheet. maybe this will help you. This is how the selection is made = Date > Region (UK & EMEA/APAC) > Tag (Finance/Sales) > Sum the number of Marketing for Region (APAC) - All this happen in different sheet and then it search in this sheet for Region (APAC) > Paste Topic (GHI) > Sum Total (9) > Tag (Marketing).

Comment: Is sheet1 and "Raw" sheet the same sheet? Why is `erow` as string? 
________________________________________________________
Show a pic of the other sheets. Better yet attach a link to a sample workbook. Like with Google Drive. Don't use a link where somebody has to sign up to open the file.

Comment: Here is the link for a sample workbook. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-yHv8Pmuj12Sk83VENZZ21MZWs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from your code exactly what you're doing but something like this should work:

```
Sub DataPasting()

    Dim RegionColumn 'variant
    Dim erow As Long
    Dim shtRaw As Worksheet, shtSaT As Worksheet, shtOne As Worksheet

    Set shtRaw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw")
    Set shtSaT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stories & Topics")
    Set shtOne = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ApplicationUpdating = False

    RegionColumn = Application.Match(shtRaw.Range("H1").Value, _
                                     shtSaT.Range("A1:Z1"), 0)

    If Not IsError(RegionColumn) Then

        erow = shtSaT.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        shtSaT.Cells(erow, RegionColumn).Resize(1, 2).Value = shtOne.Range("I2:J2").Value

    End If

    ApplicationUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, you can download the file from Google Drive link. This is what I'm trying to achieve = Select Date, Region, Tag and Run the ExtractData2 macro. You'll see the result in Sheet1. Post this I'm trying to paste this data under the correct Region and with the result in Sheet1. Hope this help.

Comment: Can someone help on this?

Comment: Well I guess I've to close the thread as No-one seems to be able to answer the query. Thanks!